# Наследование в qt

Tags: c++, qt

В моей программе есть класс `MainWindow`, который наследуется от `QMainWindow`.

*Возможно ли создать другой класс, который был бы наследником MainWindow и в файле main.cpp создать по одному объекту этих классов, и вызывать методы классов?*

Просто при попытке такой реализации методы наследника от MainWindow не выполняются.

.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent):
    QMainWindow(parent) {
        funPlot = new QwtPlot(this);
    }

...

OptionPlot:OptionPlot(QWidget *parent):
    MainWindow(parent) {
}
```

далее реализация методов классов MainWindow и OptionPlot

.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QWidget *centralWidget;
public:
    MainWindow (QWidget* parent=0);
    QwtPlot *funPlot;
}

class OptionPlot : public MainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    OptionPlot (QWidget* parent=0);
    ...
}
```

main.cpp

```
...
QApplication app(argc, argv);
MainWindow *window = new MainWindow;
OptionPlot *option1 = new OptionPlot; 

window->setPlot();
window->setGrid();
window->createMenu();

option1->setCurve();
option1->addPoints();
option1->setCheckBox();
...
return app.exec();
```

Графич. окно создается, сетка и меню тоже, а `CheckBox-ы` с графиками нет.

Comment: Покажите минимальную компилируемую программу, которая демонстрирует проблему..

Comment: Ну, и где это компилируемый пример? Как именно у вас определён `MainWindow`? Причём тут `OptionPlot`?

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в optionplot.h :`#include <QDebug>`

и в каждый метод класса OptionPlot, что-то типа этого: `qDebug()<<"выполняется метод setCurve";`

Скорее всего методы выполняются, но не так, как вы хотите.